# How to copy images in google docs paragraphs rigth?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Due the answer on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474813/it-is-necessary-to-detach-the-element-error-in-google-docs-script) I can copy content form template doc to another saving all formatting. 
But when I add some pictures to couple of paragraphs the result document shows pictures as picture logo 
[image]

The question is how to copy images right on this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adapt your `insert` method to every different element type...

an example could be like this :

```
function copyElementsByType() {
  var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.openById('yyyy');
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById('xxxx');;
  var bodyS = sourceDoc.getBody();
  var otherBody = targetDoc.getBody()();
  var elements = bodyS.getNumChildren()
  for( var e=0;e<elements;e++) {
    var element = otherBody.getChild(e).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
      body.insertParagraph(e,element)}
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE ){
      body.insertTable(e,element)}
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM ){
      body.insertListItem(e,element)}
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE ){
      body.insertImage(e,element)
    } else {
      throw new Error("check what to do with this type of element : "+type);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: O, thanks! You show me the way. In addition must say that I had to go in deeper levels.

Comment: That's the idea...go as deeper as you need for your use case!  Nevertheless could you accept it as a valid answer?  Thx

Comment: Sure. But one interesting thin - when I make images text wrapped I can get the image! I think I should ask another question.

Comment: Thank you :-)  I think it's actually a bug, there is no method for non inline image...I'll try to find the issue reference and update here.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to insert image and make it textwrap by code, but can't find such methods too (((

Comment: the issue is https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1529