# Element must be detached

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, mailmerge

I am reading a Google Sheet files and merge to a Google Document.

The template has a tables and the first line for replace text has a table.
The next line does not have a table structure and I would like to append the table until no more records.

**Description**

1. [**referral-doctor-data-new**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aw9f3htAxpIFdPyfGNzkhnFcfi1AXqaysZaVBt7D2zA/edit#gid=742388152)
   the data source to merge (monthly-q) worksheet is defined to copy fields to the google documents
2. [**accounting-monthly-statement-template**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gZruJFL7G5a9fbNN11BZHZVy_vDXDPVW03L-Bi6ePw0)
   Use as template `<<variable>>`
3. [**monthly-statement**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KyOWtlNLH8UZOrs1oCHx4_r4yQsaXYhi_7BTtlGSNCQ/edit)
   The merged document

The overview is that the template defined fields to obtain from the referral-doctor-data-new google sheet.
The monthly-q worksheet is the format of the final merged document.
I would like to Get all the detail transactions displayed in the Google Doc group by the Referral Doctor.  All the required calculations and queries are done

**Problem:**

- Can merge one data but not multiple rows of data
- I could not append the second row of the table in the google document ( I need help on this) see error element must be detached.....
- There is seems unlimited Runs of the merge process ( I will figure this out)

**Sample Files**
[Merge Files for Goolge Sheet to Goolge Doc](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E_-lS7i7z-1DDP2LpTp2P-bxU1kZAeg1?usp=sharing)

Please advise how to detach from the element.

These Lines has error

```
  // if second row of data
       body.appendTable(element).appendTableRow()
       .appendTableCell("EXAMDATE")
          .appendTableCell("VISITNO")
          .appendTableCell("PATNAME")
          .appendTableCell("PROC NAME")
          .appendTableCell("NET");
```

Complete Code

```
 ///end of mail merge
  function copy() {
    var docid=""  //merge template
var docfinalid="";//merge final doc
var sheetid="";   //raw sheet
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetid).getSheetByName("monthly-q"); 
 //var data=ss.getRange("B11:T").getValues(); // from raw table
var data=ss.getRange("A3:G").getValues(); // from monthly-q table  
var refdoc=ss.getRange("J:J").getValues() ;//get ref doc list, unique
    for (var i=0;i<refdoc.length;i++ ){
       var formula="=QUERY(raw!B10:T,\"Select C,D,H,L,M,T where M='"+refdoc[i]+"'\")";
       var qformula=ss.getRange("A2").setFormula(formula);
       data.length=0;
       data=ss.getRange("A3:G").getValues();

      
         data.forEach(function(r){
            var inv=ss.getRange("B1").getValue();//self-define invoice code
       merge(inv,"31-01-2020",r[4],"TEMPADD",r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3],r[5],r[6]);
            inv=inv+1;
 
   });
         }

 
    
  }// end of copy function 
    
  function merge(inv,date,drname,add,examdate,visitno,patname,procname,net,total) {
      var docid=""  //merge template
var docfinalid="";//merge final doc
var sheetid="";   //raw sheet
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetid).getSheetByName("raw"); 
    var doc=DocumentApp.openById(docid);
  var sourceDoc = doc.getBody();

  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(docfinalid);
  var totalElements = sourceDoc.getNumChildren();
    targetDoc.getBody().appendPageBreak();
   //get Yr from date
    //get Month from date
 
  for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
    var body = targetDoc.getBody();
    var element = sourceDoc.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();

    if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
      body.appendParagraph(element).replaceText("<<inv>>", inv)
                                      .replaceText("<<Date>>", date)
                                      .replaceText("<<Dr Name>>", drname)
                                      .replaceText("<<Address>>", add);

                           
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      body.appendTable(element).replaceText("<<Exam Date>>", examdate)
                                      .replaceText("<<Visit No>>", visitno)
                                      .replaceText("<<Patient Name>>", patname)
                                      .replaceText("<<Procedure Name>>", procname)
                                      .replaceText("<<Net Amount>>", net)
                                      .replaceText("<<Total>>", total);
      //second row of data
   
        var test=element.getParent();
 debugger;
      
     // if second row of data
       body.appendTable(element).appendTableRow()
       .appendTableCell("EXAMDATE")
          .appendTableCell("VISITNO")
          .appendTableCell("PATNAME")
          .appendTableCell("PROC NAME")
          .appendTableCell("NET");
        
    
     
    
      
      
      }else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      body.appendListItem(element);
      }
//    ...add other conditions (headers, footers...
    inv++;
    }
  targetDoc.saveAndClose();
    
}
```

I have a list of data from GoogleSheet
Merge to A Google Doc
With reference to
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474813/it-is-necessary-to-detach-the-element-error-in-google-docs-script)
I could not solve the problem

[image: Google Sheet with rows of data]
[image: Merged Google Doc]

[image: Element need to be detached]

Comment: Please create an example sheets and docs file and add it to your question. It is hard to understand without it.

Comment: Updated, please check thanks :)
I used a template to replace <<Name>> to replace a row of record.
but I have many record, and I cannot append the Google Document.

Comment: Could you create a copy of the files and use sample data so we can use that as a starting point for solving your issue?

Comment: I want to copy the current google sheet to the google document.
How to append the table written in the Document?

Comment: Please provide templates (documents, not screenshots) of the spreadsheet and docs that reproduce the issue. Replace all personal data with dummy values, but provide the correct doument structure - otherwise it is hard to reproduce your problem..

Comment: The Data structure is linked quite complicated, please look at the screenshot first, the sample data are preparing. I want to print more than one line in the merged document.  How to append the table in a google doc ?

Comment: The error `Element must be detached` comes from the fact that before copying the element you need to know which type of element it is. Modify `sourceDoc.getChild(j).copy(); ...  body.appendTable(element);` to `sourceDoc.getChild(j); ...  body.appendTable(element.asTable().copy());`. Same for paragraph. However your code seems to have also other issue. For example you cannot append a row and then append to this row several cells in the same request. I suggest you to simplify your code and then add functionalities one by one.

Comment: i changed my code to getting data join as a string
it works but i have 8500 plus records and it took too long.
unable to finish the script execution before it ends
any suggestions ?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices). If you don't find a way to optimize your code suffciently, you might have to split your request into two.